# sum and generate series does't work in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sum, generate-series

In `classification_indicator_id` column I have some digits. I would like to sum this digits in 1 day series. I wrote below query

```
select
a.data_start::date,
a.segment1::integer as "Segment1"
from (
select
    data as data_start,
    (select sum(classification_indicator_id) from classifications where classification_indicator_id = 3)::integer as segment1
from
    generate_series('2013-03-25'::timestamp without time zone,
    '2013-04-01'::timestamp without time zone,
    '1 day'::interval) data
) a
group by
a.data_start,
a.segment1
ORDER BY data_start
```

But I always getting something like:

```
date start|segment1
-------------------
2013-03-25|39
2013-03-26|39
2013-03-27|39
2013-03-28|39
2013-03-29|39
2013-03-30|39
2013-03-31|39
2013-04-01|39
```

I am sure that should be something like:

```
date start|segment1
-------------------
2013-03-25|3
2013-03-26|4
2013-03-27|7
2013-03-28|9
2013-03-29|15
2013-03-30|22
2013-03-31|19
2013-04-01|5
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f4d98/1)

Comment: Can there be days with no classifications at all? And would you want to list those days with a count of `0`? You would also have to provide the table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script) for a precise answer. It depends on whether columns can be `NULL` and whether you want to count those or not.

Comment: Yes, some day has no classifications. And I want list those days.
I modified a bit answer that @Clodoaldo Neto sent. I post it as a new answer. [link to table definition](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f1bec/1)

Comment: I will create new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    data.d::date,
    coalesce(sum(classification_indicator_id), 0)::integer as "Segment1"
from 
    classifications c
    right join
    generate_series(
        '2013-03-25'::timestamp without time zone,
        '2013-04-01'::timestamp without time zone,
        '1 day'::interval
    ) data(d) on data.d::date = c.data_start::date
where classification_indicator_id = 3
group by 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's wokring great:)

Comment: But how to modify this query to add additional column for example `where classification_indicator_id = 4` `where classification_indicator_id = 6` etc.

Comment: @infaustus You can do it by adding columns or by doing group level totalizator. Think about what exactly you want and open another question.

Comment: `COALESCE` should not be necessary, `sum()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: @Erwin If all the summed values are null the result will be null. Check `select sum(a) is null from (values (null::integer)) s(a)`. I guess he wants a zero in that case. You can argue I should have "coalesced" the result of the `sum` in instead of each value and you would be right. Be free to edit it if you think it makes a difference.

Comment: Then it should be `coalesce(sum( ...` instead of `sum(coalesce( ...` for a cost of O(1) instead of O(n). I applied it.

Answer (score 0):

I need to add some other columns (with another `classification_indicator_id`
I modified a bit your answer:

```
select
data.d::date as "data",
sum(c.classification_indicator_id)::integer as "Segment1",
sum(c4.classification_indicator_id)::integer as "Segment2",
sum(c5.classification_indicator_id)::integer as "Segment3"
from 
  generate_series(
    '2013-03-25'::timestamp without time zone,
    '2013-04-01'::timestamp without time zone,
    '1 day'::interval
) data(d)
left join classifications c on (data.d::date = c.created::date and c.classification_indicator_id = 3)
left join classifications c4 on (data.d::date = c4.created::date and c4.classification_indicator_id = 4)
left join classifications c5 on (data.d::date = c5.created::date and c5.classification_indicator_id = 5)
group by "data"
ORDER BY "data"
```

But still not working properly. `sum` for each row is to big, and growing when I add additional columns

```
With 4 columns                          With 3 column
data      |Segment1|Segment2|Segment3   data      |Segment1|Segment2
-------------------------------------   ----------------------------
2013-03-25|12      |16      |20         2013-03-25|12      |16      
-------------------------------------   ----------------------------
2013-03-26|108     |144     |180        2013-03-26|18      |24
```

Comment: This may produce a "proxy cross join". If there are multiple matching rows in `c`, `c4`, or `c5`, they form a **`CROSS JOIN`**, multiplying their count, which is most probably not what you want. Consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135